# Why is wrapping inconsistent in C# Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, word-wrap

Using this code:

```
var avgOrderAmountHeaderCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_COLUMN_HEADER_ROW, AVG_ORDER_AMOUNT_COLUMN];
avgOrderAmountHeaderCell.Value2 = String.Format("Avg Order{0}Amount", Environment.NewLine);
avgOrderAmountHeaderCell.WrapText = true;

var avgPackageCountHeaderCell = (Range)_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_COLUMN_HEADER_ROW, AVG_PACKAGE_AMOUNT_COLUMN];
avgPackageCountHeaderCell.Value2 = String.Format("Avg Package{0}Count", Environment.NewLine);
avgPackageCountHeaderCell.WrapText = true;
```

...I get this result (column header on left looks fine, while the one on the right has an "empty line" between the second and third wrapped line):

[image]

Why is this seemingly arbitrary inconsistent implementation of text wrapping taking place, and more importantly, how can I force no "blank lines" to appear between one line of text and another?

Comment: what happens if you set the column widths accordingly as well as turn off word wrapping.. have you tried that

Comment: I use Autofit, so prefer not to tweak individual column widths. I had to do it for one column, anyway, because it was breaking a word over two lines, but in general I don't want to have to specify the width of individual columns when Autofit should right-width them.

Comment: what happens when you have it AutoFit...? why are you wrapping the text anyway..

Comment: I am using Autofit. I am wrapping so that the columns are not too wide - the column headers (such as shown in the post) are way longer than the contents of the cells (the related data). And, I'm replicating the look of an existing made-by-hand spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason you are using Excel Interop instead of [Open Xml for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)? It has been the recommended way to manipulate documents ever since it's release in office 2003 and the `xlsx` file type.

Comment: Had I known that a couple of months ago, I may have looked at that quite intensely, but the legacy code uses Interop and, for the most part, it works really well.

Comment: And Aspose Cells is tempting - I've heard it's a trillion times faster, which would be kind of nice; if so, it could even make time run backwards.